# Creating a trigger to store an audit trail

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have to create a trigger on the Claims table that is triggered whenever a new record is inserted into the Claims table. This trigger should store the customer name and the total `amount_of_claim` by that customer.

Claim_audits (audit table) have already been created.

Schema:

```
Claims

id int(11)
status_id int(11)
customer_policy_id int(11)
date_of_claim date
amount_of_claim float

> one or many to one(and only one) towards Customer_policy

Customer_policy

id int(11)
policy_start_date date
policy_renewal_date date
policy_id int(11)
customer_id int(11)
agent_id(11)

> one or many to one (and only one) towards Customer

Customer

id int(11)
first_name varchar(30)
last_name varchar(30)
email varchar(30)
address_id int(11)
```

Output should look like this:

```
customer_name   amount_of_claim
abhinav         195000
```

This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER claim_audits on claims 
for insert
as
    declare @custname varchar(25);
    declare @amount varchar(25);
    declare @action varchar(25);
    
    select @custname = first_name from customer c
    join inserted i on i.id=c.id;
    select @amount = i.amount_of_claim from inserted i;
    select @action = 'Updated customer claimed amount';
    
    insert into claim_audits values(@custname , @amount , @action);
    select * from claim_audits; 
go
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is read about the [Inserted and Deleted pseudo-tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15), because they can have 0-N rows... not just 1. And what have you noticed not working about your trigger? And why are you selecting `* from claim_audits` at the end? Its very bad practice to select within a trigger... what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DaleK but won't this be only triggered after insert query so it will always have atleast one record??

Comment: What if it has 2 records? What if it has 0 records?

Comment: This requirement "This trigger should store the customer name and the total amount_of_claim by that customer." could be taken to mean the total over multiple claims?

Comment: `amount_of_claim float` float is approximate value. Use `decimal` or `numeric` instead.

Comment: @DaleK if I had to store the amount over multiple claims for the same person , would I have to add a variable inside to add each claim to the sum??

Comment: @ShubhamPanwar - check my answer - you are using SQL, use set-based logic. Provide some sample data and expected results to illustrate all the use cases you need to handle.

Comment: @ShubhamPanwar also putting the total claim amount if the client has multiple claims, is in my opinion meaningless. But I guess it really comes down to, what are you using this audit table for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Inserted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) pseudo-table can have 0-N rows, and you need to handle that. And as with anything SQL related you should approach it using a set-based approach - not a procedural approach.

You also don't appear to have been obtaining the customer id correctly - at least based on your table definitions. I must say, its very odd to be storing the first name of the customer in your audit table. Why not store the customer id? The name is not unique, so you haven't provided a reliable audit trail.

```
create trigger claim_audits
on claims
for insert
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    insert into dbo.claim_audits (custname, amount, [action])
        select C.first_name, I.amount_of_claim, 'Updated customer claimed amount'
        from Inserted I
        inner join Customer_Policy CP on CP.id = I.customer_policy_id
        inner join Customer C on C.id = CP.customer_id;
end;
```

Note - you do not want to be attempting to return data from a trigger.

And as pointed out by @Squirral: `amount_of_claim float`: float is an approximate value and should never be used for money. Use decimal or numeric instead.